# Can the subject be in dative rather than in nominative case?

Tags: grammatical-case, subject

I need some clarification on the following sentences.

> 1. Der Feldmaus gefiel das Leben in der Stadt nicht.
> 2. Das Leben in der Stadt gefiel der Feldmaus  nicht.

I’m sitting in German class and our teacher tells me *mouse* is the subject of the sentence. While I say the subject of the sentance is *life in the city* since it is in accusative and the *mouse* is in dative. I understand the subject can be in the first or third position.

Comment: *Das Leben* is the subject and hence better be in the nominative case! Luckily it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Der Feldmaus** *Dativobjekt*
>   **gefällt** *Prädikat*
>   **das Leben** **in der Stadt** *Subjekt (und daher im Nominativ) mit präpositionaler Dativergänzung*.

So you're right with your definition of the subject, but its case is (always) **nominative**, not accusative. The subject can indeed be in the first or third position.

There are **very few** constructions that allow to leave out the subject:

> **Mir** ist kalt.

In this case, there's only a Dativobjekt. Maybe this got your teacher confused.

Comment: In »Es ist mir kalt« ist das *es* ein rein syntaktisches Expletiv und hat nichts mit dem Subjekt zu tun. Diesen Fall muss man unterscheiden von Fällen wie »Es regnet heute.« In Letzterem bleibt das Subjekt-*Es* erhalten, wenn ich den Satz umstelle (»Heute regnet es«), während im Ersteren das *Es* verschwindet »Mir ist kalt.« Folglich handelt es sich bei »Mir ist kalt« um einen völlig subjektlosen Satz.

Comment: @Jan Wie du selbst sagst: das 'es' *verschwindet*.

Comment: Nein, der Punkt ist, dass »Mir ist kalt« bereits der vollständige Satz ist. Im Grunde kann ich fast jeden Satz mit einem entsprechenden Expletiv ausrüsten: »Es gingen zwei Jungen am Sonntag um kurz vor zehn in die Kirceh des Dorfes …«, was das *es* noch lange nicht zum Subjekt (hier: *zwei Jungen)* macht. Nur dort wo das *es* bei Umstellung **erhalten** bleibt, kann es Subjekt sein (»Heute regnet **es«).**

Comment: @Jan *"Es war ihm nicht kalt" if you wanted to put emphasis on the subject, you could phrase it like that.* Das war deine Antwort auf die Frage *Why “es” exists in “Ihm war es nicht kalt.”?*

Comment: Hier laufen mehrere Jans herum. Der Jan, der die Frage beantwortet hat, hat die User-ID [10808](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/10808). Ich habe die User-ID [15318](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/15318). Ich distanziere mich hiermit ausdrücklich von seiner (falschen) Feststellung und werde seine Antwort mit –1 und einem Kommentar ausstatten.

Comment: @Jan Sorry für die Verwechslung. Ich werde meine Antwort anders formulieren.

Answer (score 6):

A shorter example:

> Der Film gefällt mir.

*Der Film* is in the nominative case and the subject, *mir* is a dative object.

In the same way, in your example *das Leben in der Stadt* is the subject (nominative) and *der Feldmaus* is a dative. Note that *Maus* is feminine.

Comment: Make it even simpler - *Der Film gefällt* - A valid German sentence consisting only of subject and predicate.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is always in the nominative case.

Unlike English, where the subject is (almost) "always" in the first position, that is often not true in German.

In German, a verb is always in the second position in a declarative sentence, but the first position can contain a subject, a direct object, or an indirect object. That's why you need "declensions" to tell them apart.

In the sentence, Der Feldmaus gefiel das Leben in der Stadt nicht, der Feldmaus is in the dative case, hence is an indirect object, and das Leben... is in the nominative case, and hence is the subject. Their respective placements in the first and third positions is probably what confused you.